# Loss/accuracy on Synthetic data

Tags: data-science

I am trying to understand if there is any difference in the the interpretation of accuracy and loss on synthetic data vs real data.

Comment: So, what is your specific question? Can you elaborate more? Why do you think there would be a difference?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no difference.

Of course, you are likely not able to extrapolate results obtained from synthetic data to expect identical or similar results in real life to unless you have **very** compelling reasons to do so.

Without a more specific question, I'm afraid a more specific answer is not possible.